# Typo3 + solr : show extra field in search

Tags: solr, typo3

I've added a field inside my config :

```
        'effective_start' => [
        'exclude' => FALSE,
        'label' => 'Date d\'ouverture (pour l\'affichage)',
        'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 16,
            'eval' => 'trim',
        ],
    ],
```

How to I add this **effective_start** field into my solr result page on each result ?

I've tried this, but the value in **effective_start** is always empty, even if there is a value (I can see it in my database and in my backend). I just need to get this value, not passing it in facets (but the only way I found to get a value, is to add a facet and hide it...)

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.[myContentName].fields {
    title = title
    #effective_start = effective_start
    abstract = teaser
    abstract = TEXT
    abstract {
        field = teaser
    } ...
    effective_startS = TEXT
    effective_startS {
        field = effective_startS
    }
}

plugin.tx_solr.search.results.fieldRenderingInstructions {
    effective_start =< plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.effective_start.renderingInstruction
    effective_start.field = effective_startS
}

plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting {
    facets.effective_start {
        field = effective_startS
        renderingInstruction = TEXT
    }
}
```

EDIT :
I've extended a template field and I'm displaying my document thanks to this :

```
<!-- ###LOOP:RESULT_DOCUMENTS### begin -->
<!-- ###LOOP_CONTENT### -->
<!--
    Score: ###RESULT_DOCUMENT.SCORE###
    Document ID:  ###RESULT_DOCUMENT.ID###
-->
    "###RESULT_DOCUMENT###" //display all value
    "###RESULT_DOCUMENT.effective_startS###"
<!-- ###LOOP_CONTENT### -->
<!-- ###LOOP:RESULT_DOCUMENTS### end -->
```

Display all values dump all documents serialized values, and effective_start is show this :

```
"effective_start";s:0:""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend solr templates. You do it by copying `EXT:Resources/Private/Partials/Result/Document.html` to some other place and modify that file to include your field. Example:

```html
<div class="results-teaser">
    <p class="result-content">{s:document.highlightResult(resultSet:resultSet, document:document, fieldName:'content')}</p>

    <p>{document.effective_startS}</p>
```

Then you add the directory for this partial to TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
    view {
        partialRootPaths {
            20 = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Plugin/Solr/Partials/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have extended my template, but the field is not showing (effective_start, effective_startS, effective_start_string, effective_start_stringS... I've tried them all !)

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out why, but changing the camel case and adding a size in my input definition make it worked ...

```
effectiveStart_stringS = effective_start
effectiveStart_stringS = TEXT
effectiveStart_stringS {
    field = effective_start
}
```

Comment: That's right because `_startS` is not a valid field suffix according to solr docs.